# Execute Jenkins build based on multiple triggers

Tags: jenkins

I have two builds that are triggered periodically,

-first build runs every night

-second build runs every week

how do I trigger weekly build every week but only if the daily build of the day beforehand have passed successfully ?

Comment: First, try to understand like CRON works, then you understand the Jenkins triggers.
Second, you need to read the information of the last run, you can read via REST from Jenkins self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the weekly job, I would suggest checking the build status of the first job in a bash script step and continue or exit the job based on the first job build status. You can do that by doing `curl` on that job, something like this:

`curl -u ${USERNAME}:${TOKEN} http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastCompletedBuild/api/json`

The `${USERNAME}:${TOKEN}` should be only needed if you are using authentication on your server. From the `curl` response you can then `grep` for the `result` and continue with the logic - quit the job if the result is not success or whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the good answer from Petr, if you have the "jq" command available to you, you can easily get the result

```
curl -u ${USERNAME}:${TOKEN} http://<jenkins_url>/job/<job_name>/lastCompletedBuild/api/json | jq '.result'
```

Returns "SUCCESS" if the previous job was successful